# Acesso negado ao deletar Registry (até no regedit)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

Estou tentando apagar um registro do Windows utilizando o Delphi porém sem sucesso (até mesmo com o próprio Regedit não consigo).

Código que estou utilizando:

```
Function DeleteKeyAPI(hRoot: HKEY; sPath: String; IsReg64: BOOL): BOOL;
Var
  iRet: Integer;
Begin
  If IsReg64 Then
    iRet := RegDeleteKeyEx(hRoot, PChar(sPath), KEY_WOW64_64KEY, 0)
  Else
    iRet := RegDeleteKeyEx(hRoot, PChar(sPath), KEY_WOW64_32KEY, 0);

  If iRet = ERROR_SUCCESS Then
    Result := True
  Else
    Result := False;
End;
```

Mensagem de erro quando tento excluir pelo Regedit:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando eu deleto pelo software (PC Hunter) o mesmo e deletado com sucesso.
Como posso fazer para deletar esse Registro?

Comment: O usuário precisa ter permissão de acesso ao registro, senão não dá. Clique com o botão direito na entrada e veja a parte de segurança/credenciais para entender melhor. Muito provavelmente o que o soft mencionado fez foi alterar as permissões antes da remoção.

Comment: Como vc está forçando o registro com as flags KEY_WOW64_64/32KEY, chegou a verificar se a variável IsReg64 está correta para o caso? De acordo com o caminho no seu screenshot, só funcionaria com IsReg64 em false, pois a chave está em Wow6432Node. (aplicação 32 bits rodando em 64)

Comment: Se nem no regedit você está conseguindo deve ser permissão.
Tenta verificar se seu usuário está como administrador em: Iniciar > Executar > comando: control userpasswords2